# Cant patch mongoDB/express

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, redux, axios

I have a react, redux and mongoDB app with a users collection, each user has a favorites array which I want to update with a patch everytime a user adds a favorite element, but my patch method always returns error with a 404 (Not Found). Here's my code:

Action:

```
export const saveToUser = info => dispatch => {
axios
.patch('api/users', info)
    .then( res => {
        dispatch({
            type:SAVE_TO_USER,
            payload:info
        })
        dispatch( getUsers() )
    }).catch( err => console.log(err))
```

}

users.js

```
router.patch('/:id', (req,res) => {
User.update({ googleId: req.body.googleId },
    { $push: { favorites: req.body.site } })
});
```

server.js

```
const users = require('./routes/api/users')
app.use('/api/users', users);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed myself. My query was wrong, it shoud be:

```
router.patch('/', (req,res) => {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: "userId" },
        { favorites: ["Here something"] },
        function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
          } else {
            res.send(result);
          }
        }
      );
});
```